# Fullcalendar Google pop up events

Tags: javascript, popup, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to do an embed of google's calendar into a website. The iframe google provides is functional and provides a pop up when you click the event that displays the event information. That's quite nice.

However, the google calendar as they provide it is relatively ugly. So I found fullcalendar and have been tweaking it to have a prettier overall interface to display events it pulls from google calendar via api. I've gotten it nearly where I want it, but for the life of me I can not get those pop ups that google's iframe displays so freely back into Fullcalendar.

Is the pop up (screenshot from the google iframe embed) displayed here possible to get into Fullcalendar and I am just missing how it is done?

[screenshot of pop up I am trying to recreate in Fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIfM8.png)

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found another article using a different item to achieve the goal.

[FullCalendar event click through FancyBox (v2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957822/fullcalendar-event-click-through-fancybox-v2?rq=1)

Comment: were you able to resolve this using your given link? Can I see a screenshot of your "working implementation"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Google Calendar for FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/demos/gcal.html), I don't think this is directly supported. However, you can try coding this pop-up implementation. There's a tutorial on how to do this using [JQuery, HTML or NodeJS](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar-with-ui-modal-dialog/). Here's a [demo](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/fullcalendar-jquery-ui-modal/).

[image]